# Unclicking listview elements

Tags: java, android, listview

I am creating a listview where people can tick off books on the listview as they read them. When they select a book the alpha of the row goes to 0.2f and a toast appears telling them they read the book. I'm trying to make it so that when a book has been selected they can also unselect it by clicking on it again, which will put the alpha back to 1f.

I have created an if else loop in the onItemClick method which is allowing me to unselect clicked rows, however it is following a pattern where the first click goes to 0.2f, the second goes to 1f, the third goes to 0.2f and so on. Instead I would like only rows that are at 0.2f to be able to go to 1f and vice versa.

This is my code:

```
public class Books extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ListView booksListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.booksListView);

    final ArrayList<String> topBooks = new ArrayList<String>(asList("1984", "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Pride and Prejudice",
            "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", "The Great Gatsby","Jane Eyre","Wuthering Heights","The Catcher in the Rye",
            "The Hobbit","Brave New World","The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring","Don Quixote",
            "Catch-22","The Count of Monte Cristo","Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire","The Grapes of Wrath","The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
            "The Diary of a Young Girl","Gone with the Wind","Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows","Moby Dick","Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince","War and Peace",
            "Animal Farm","Anna Karenina","Ulysses","Lord of the Flies","The Divine Comedy","One Hundred Years of Solitude","Frankenstein","The Perks of Being a Wallflower",
            "The Fault in Our Stars","Good to Great","Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets","Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix","Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
            "The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay","The Hunger Games","The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers","The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", "The Maze Runner",
            "Looking for Alaska","Fahrenheit 451", "Hamlet","Gullivers Travels","The Canterbury Tales","Rebecca","The Brothers Karamazov","Lover Awakened","At Grave's End"));

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, topBooks);

    booksListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.pindrop);

    booksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(view.getAlpha()==1f) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Read " + topBooks.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                view.animate().alpha(0.2f);
                mPlayer.start();
            }

            else {

                view.animate().alpha(1f);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you have to store read or unread status of book for each item and on the basis of that boolean flag you can set alpha of each row.

Comment: try getting listview item position onClick, and then check conditions. Right now you are using the boolean for the list, not the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the other two answers with your code in mind, Create a BookAdapter, a BookModel and then xml for the book row:

xml for the book row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the BookModel:

```
public class BookModel {

    public String name;
    public boolean isRead;

}
```

the BookAdapter:

```
public class BookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<BookModel> books;

    static class Holder{
        TextView mTvName;
    }

    public BookAdapter(Context context, List<BookModel> books){
        this.context = context;
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return books.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return books.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_row, parent, false);

            holder = new Holder();

            holder.mTvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final BookModel bookModel = books.get(position);

        if(bookModel != null){

            holder.mTvName.setText(bookModel.name);

            if(bookModel.isRead){
                holder.mTvName.animate().alpha(0.2f);
                bookModel.isRead = true;
            }else{
                holder.mTvName.animate().alpha(1f);
                bookModel.isRead = false;
            }
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Book Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.divshark.booksample.Books">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/booksListView"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then implement your Activity **EDIT - Now book reading is persisted in preferences**:

```
public class Books extends AppCompatActivity {

    public List<BookModel> books;
    private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SharedPrefs";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_books);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        ListView booksListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.booksListView);

        books = createBooks();


        final BookAdapter adapter = new BookAdapter(this, books);

        booksListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pindrop);

        booksListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                final BookModel bookModel = books.get(position);
                if (!bookModel.isRead) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Read " + bookModel.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    view.animate().alpha(0.2f);
                    mPlayer.start();
                    bookModel.isRead = true;

                    if(mSharedPreferences != null){
                        mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(bookModel.name, bookModel.isRead).apply();
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {

                    view.animate().alpha(1f);
                    mPlayer.start();
                    bookModel.isRead = false;

                    if(mSharedPreferences != null){
                        mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(bookModel.name, bookModel.isRead).apply();
                    }

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ArrayList<BookModel>
     * @return - List<BookModel>
     */
    public List<BookModel> createBooks(){

        final ArrayList<String> topBooks = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1984", "To Kill a Mockingbird", "Pride and Prejudice",
                "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", "The Great Gatsby", "Jane Eyre", "Wuthering Heights", "The Catcher in the Rye",
                "The Hobbit", "Brave New World", "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", "Don Quixote",
                "Catch-22", "The Count of Monte Cristo", "Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire", "The Grapes of Wrath", "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn",
                "The Diary of a Young Girl", "Gone with the Wind", "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows", "Moby Dick", "Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince", "War and Peace",
                "Animal Farm", "Anna Karenina", "Ulysses", "Lord of the Flies", "The Divine Comedy", "One Hundred Years of Solitude", "Frankenstein", "The Perks of Being a Wallflower",
                "The Fault in Our Stars", "Good to Great", "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets", "Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix", "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban",
                "The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay", "The Hunger Games", "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", "The Maze Runner",
                "Looking for Alaska", "Fahrenheit 451", "Hamlet", "Gullivers Travels", "The Canterbury Tales", "Rebecca", "The Brothers Karamazov", "Lover Awakened", "At Grave's End"));

        List<BookModel> books = new ArrayList<>(topBooks.size());

        for(int i = 0; i < topBooks.size(); i++){
            BookModel bookModel = new BookModel();
            bookModel.name = topBooks.get(i);

            if(mSharedPreferences != null) {
                // sets the IsRead field from value in preferences
                bookModel.isRead =   mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(bookModel.name, false);
            }else {

                bookModel.isRead = false;

                // Open preferences to write the value in on load
                mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                // Stores the book in shared preferences as un-read
                mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(bookModel.name, false).apply();
            }

            books.add(bookModel);
        }

        return books;
    }
}
```

and styles just in case you need them:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just one other question, is there a way that the app can save the selections the user makes, so that if I close the emulator the same books will be clicked when I reopen it?

Comment: @BelovedAunt of course you can store the values for the books in SQLiteDatabase or since this is so simple you can use SharedPreferences and right the values to that.

Comment: @BelovedAunt see the Activity code above which has been modified to persist your books reading.

Comment: When I tried to implement your code the app was crashing so I did it a different way using an if else loop. I've updated my code at the top. Just wondering if it's possible to save the books that are clicked using my code, or if that's not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom adapter along with a toggle selection function to achieve the expected behaviour. Here's an example.

```
public class ToggleSelectionListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    public ToggleSelectionListAdapter(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selectedItems.size();
    }

    public void clearSelections() {
        selectedItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // Initialize your items of each row here
        }

        public void bindView(int pos) {
            try {
                if (mCursor.isClosed())
                    return;

                mCursor.moveToPosition(pos);

                // Maintain a checked item list so that you can have a track if the item is clicked or not
                if (checkedItems.contains(number) itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selected);
                else itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_normal);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (checkedItems.contains(number)) {
                                    checkedItems.remove(number);
                                } else {
                                    checkedItems.add(number);
                                }

                            // Get the index of which item should toggle the background
                            int idx = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                            toggleSelection(idx);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;

        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) holder;

            vh.bindView(position);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        if (mCursor == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int n = mCursor.getCount();
        return n;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    synchronized public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```